# refactor multi if statements and checking for div existence in a better style

Tags: javascript

I want to refactor this code to a better version without all this repetition, this code is working 100% the way it is right now but every refactoring effort is making it useless, any idea or can this be considered the maximum ?

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.results')

  if (results < 0) {
    let item = `<div class="center"><p class="statmentminus">bad!</p></div>`
    if (div.parentElement.querySelector('.statmentplus')) {
      let toRemove = div.parentElement.querySelector('.statmentplus')
      toRemove.remove()
    }
    if (div.parentElement.querySelector('.statmentminus')) return
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", item)
  }
  if (results > 0) {
    let item = `<div class="center"><p class="statmentplus">good!</p></div>`
    if (afterDiv.parentElement.querySelector('.statmentminus')) {
      let toRemove = div.parentElement.querySelector('.statmentminus')
      toRemove.remove()
    }
    if (afterDiv.parentElement.querySelector('.statmentplus')) return
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", item)
  }
```

Comment: So that we can advise you properly, please provide context so that we can understand what this code accomplishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reducing source complexity

There is a rule in coding, *"If it works leave it alone!"*

However when developing code you should aim for simplicity in code, that includes keeping code D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Its way to late to write good code if you need to change working code.

### Drying out your code

Suggestions to reduce complexity.

- Use [`?.` (Optional chaining)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when calling functions. It lets you test if the result of a query is not `undefined`/`null` before calling the function.
- Use [`?` (Conditional operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to simplify assignments. This lets you assign to constants based on a condition which is not possible using if statements.

  In this case the condition is `result` is negative or not.

  Or with just the [`?` (Conditional operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) you can select a item based on a condition.

  See rewrites...
- Store repeated literals as constants [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) .

### Rewrite

The code you provided is lacking some context meaning the rewrite must make some guesses.

- What is `result`? What possible values can it have? It is assumed that it is always a number. That its value is never 0
- There are `return`s yet no function has been defined. It is unclear where other returns should be. It is assumed to be at the end.

Because of these points I did not check the following rewrites for syntax or correctness. They are examples of how, they are not solutions

```
const div = document.querySelector('.results'), par = div.parentElement;
const cn = [".statmentplus", ".statmentminus"];
const [remove, ignore, text] = result > 0 ? [cn[1], cn[0], "Good!"] : [cn[0], cn[1], "bad!"];
par.querySelector(remove)?.remove();
if (!par.querySelector(ignore)) {  
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", 
        `<div class="center"><p class="statmentminus">${text}</p></div>`);
}
```

Or

```
const CLASS_NAMES = [".statmentplus", ".statmentminus"];
const div = document.querySelector('.results');
const [good, par] = [result > 0, div.parentElement];
par.querySelector(CLASS_NAMES[good ? 1 : 0])?.remove();
if (!par.querySelector(CLASS_NAMES[good ? 0 : 1])) {  
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", 
        `<div class="center"><p class="statmentminus">${good ? "GOOD" : "BAD"}</p></div>`);
}
```

Or

```
const [CLASS_NAMES, REPLYS] = [[".statmentplus", ".statmentminus"], ["BAD", "GOOD"]];
const div = document.querySelector('.results'), par = div.parentElement;
const good = result > 0 ? 1 : 0;
par.querySelector(CLASS_NAMES[good])?.remove();
!par.querySelector(CLASS_NAMES[good ? 0 : 1]) && div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", 
    `<div class="center"><p class="statmentminus">${REPLYS[good]}</p></div>`);
```